# Application Version in Header (SOAP)

Tags: api, soap

I am using C# SOAP API, and would like to place the application version number in the header file, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a App version key under header and add the app version into the tag. For details [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1137408.aspx?Adding%20information%20to%20the%20SOAP%20Header)

Comment: sorry I'm not getting it, could you explain more please?